# Windows 11 error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'

Tags: ros

My Python version is 3.8, but he still reports that the module cannot be found. I developed it on Windows 11 system. Do have anyone who has encountered this problem? Can share how to solve it? Thanks

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'

The C extension 'C:\ros2-windows\Lib\site-packages\_rclpy_pybind11.pyd' isn't present on the system. Please refer to 'https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-without-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions
```

```shell
C:\ros2-windows>python --version
Python 3.8.3
```